# matching either of category ids provided in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have following elastic search parameters.

I am trying to search for category types with anyone of the ids in the query.

However the search parameters below are fetching all category types.

```
{
  "size": 25,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "organization_id": "dummy_organization"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "object_type": "category"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "should": [
                    {
                      "match": {
                        "category_type_id": "94f7dc26b611a5c2"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "match": {
                        "category_type_id": "b630613358520d51"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": [

                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "category_name": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the minimum should match count on the shoulds.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html#bool-min-should-match

```
You can use the minimum_should_match parameter to specify the number or percentage of should clauses returned documents must match.

If the bool query includes at least one should clause and no must or filter clauses, the default value is 1. Otherwise, the default value is 0.
```

You could probably also simplify your query:

```
{
  "size": 25,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "organization_id": "dummy_organization"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "object_type": "category"
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "category_type_id": "94f7dc26b611a5c2"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "category_type_id": "b630613358520d51"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "category_name": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```